# Correctly angling Div to point to cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a div inside a container that points to the cursor. The issue is that the accuracy is off and I need to change the angle.

*HTML*

```
<div class="shooting_container">
            <div class="shooter">
                <div class="shooting_arm">
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.shooter {
    height: 480px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    bottom: 150px;
    margin: 0 100px;
    position: absolute;

    .shooting_arm {
        height: 245px;
        width: 166px;
        bottom: 500px;
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - 40px);
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-12deg);
        z-index: 500;
        transform-origin: 156px 8px;
        left: -43px;
    background-color: red;

    // Where the transform origin lies
        &::after {
          position: absolute;
          top: 8px;
          left: 156px;
          width: 5px;
          height: 5px;
          content: '';
          background-color: #f0f;
          border-radius: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }



    }

}
```

*JS*

```
$(document).on('mousemove', moveCursor);

function moveCursor(e) {

    var box = $(".shooter .shooting_arm");

    var boxCenter = [box.offset().left+box.width()/2, box.offset().top+box.height()/2];

    var angle = Math.atan2(e.pageX - boxCenter[0], - (e.pageY - boxCenter[1]) )*(180/Math.PI) - 180;      

    if (angle < -160) {
        angle = -0;
    }
    setArm(box, angle);

}
function setArm(arm, angle) {
    arm.css({ "-webkit-transform": 'translateY(-50%) rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});    
    arm.css({ '-moz-transform': 'translateY(-50%) rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
}
```

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrWJwZ

**Problem 1: Angle is incorrect and differs as you move**

Incorrect angle. I need the top of the container to align with the cursor, not the center. I tried adjusting:

```
var boxCenter = [box.offset().left+box.width()/2, box.offset().top+box.height()/2];
```

to

```
var boxCenter = [box.offset().left+box.width()/2, box.offset().top+box.height()/2/2];
```

But it still was not in line with the top of the container.

[image]

**Problem 2: Glitches when cursor is within the div itself**

For some reason it returns two different angle values when the cursor is within the container and causes it to jiggle. Why does it do this?

[image]

Comment: How did you make that gif?

Comment: I am not sure why you deviate the angle under -160, plus -0 doesn' t exist: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKVLwZ

Comment: I made the gif using Gyazo. @vega - I don't want the div to point at the mouse during those angles. I used -0 to keep it consistent with the other angles in the negatives. Thank you very much for your codepen. It has sorted the second issue for sure! But the div is not correctly pointing to the cursor. It is also now upside down using the incorrect side to point to the cursor. Also when I move my cursor up or down the angle still changes and doesn't stay inline all the time. I'm still struggling over this